# Retrieve value from popup jsp to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am opening a popup window (JSP page) using JavaScript.

I am setting some value in the popup and doing `window.close()`.

Now, I am to return that value to the main page from where I had opened the popup through JavaScript.

How can I retrieve the value?

Comment: you could save the value to a cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **jsp page** add this :

```
function onPopupClose(returnParameter) {
   // Process returnParameter here
}

window.open('popup.jsp?parameter='+param,'mywindow','width=500,height=350,toolba‌​r=no,resizable=no,menubar=no');
```

Then in your **popup jsp**, before calling `window.close` , add this line :

```
window.opener.onPopupClose(myValue);//myValue is the value you want to return to main javascript
window.close();
```

Comment: I tried it i wrote like this: In my java script i wrote var valueFromPopup; var returnParameter = window.open('popup.jsp?parameter='+param,'mywindow','width=500,height=350,toolbar=no,resizable=no,menubar=no'); if(returnParameter != null){ alert('ReturnFormPopUp:'+valueFromPopup);

and in my popup.jsp i wrote
window.opener.valueFromPopup = userName;
    window.close(); 

But when i am trying to run before the window opens i am getting the alert as undefined :(

Comment: window.open won't return a value. Instead it returns an handle on the newly opened window.

Comment: you're welcome. Don't forget to click to mark the answer as accepted. This will indicate your question as solved ;)